# laravel 5 form request validation issue

Tags: laravel-5

in my laravel 5.1 app, I've got a Book model with a required "Title" field and several others non-required fields. To validate Book create/update, I use form request validation like this:

```
class StoreBookRequest extends Request
{

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'required',
            'year' => 'numeric',
            'pages' => 'numeric',
        ];
    }
}
```

I then type-hint the request on the controller action and everytning works fine. Now I need to create a new controller action that updates only one of the non-required fields. To do so, I created another request like this:

```
class StoreReviewRequest extends Request
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'vote' => 'numeric',
        ];
    }
}
```

and I type-hint the request in the controller action:

```
public function updateReview(StoreReviewRequest $request, Book $book)
{
    $input = array_except(Input::all(), '_method');
    $book->update($input);
    Session::flash('message', 'Review updated');

    return redirect('/book');
}
```

The problem is that when I use the new controller action, the update form does not pass validation, but complains about missing "Title" field, even tough I'm not decalring that field as required in my StoreReviewRequest class. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You've declared `'title'=>'required'` in your rules. That's why it shows the field is required.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right controller when submitting the form?

Comment: @JilsonThomas in the uodateReview action I'm using StoreReviewRequest  and there's no 'title' => required there.

Comment: @Needpoule yes, the controller is the right one.

Comment: Can you show your form?

Comment: @Needpoule damn, you were right. In my form I was using the right controller, but wrong method. Silly mistake. Sorry to bother and thanks for the help!

Comment: @vonblubba no problem, glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

As @Needpoule suggested, I was using the wrong action in my form.